# How to animate other rows moving out of the way when reordering table rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

Some of the tables in my web application can be reordered with drag and drop, using this code:

http://isocra.com/2007/07/dragging-and-dropping-table-rows-in-javascript/

This uses the standard JavaScript insertBefore method to move a table to a different DOM position, like this:

```
dragObject.parentNode.insertBefore(dragObject, currentRow.nextSibling);
```

It works fine, but the movement seems abrupt. I would like to update this so that as I drag a table row, the other rows animate to their new positions. This is the same effect that iOS has when you drag a table row in an editable table.

I thought this could be a job for jQuery, so I tweaked the code to change the standard insertBefore methods to jQuery's insertBefore functions, which I thought I could then animate:

```
jQuery(".dragging").insertBefore(currentRow.nextSibling)
```

But after playing with different animation options I realized that they could only animate the row that's moving, not the other rows around it.

Has anyone seen a solution for this -- basically simulating the iOS table reordering in HTML? I would prefer a solution that works with my existing table rows so I don't have to completely change my code, but I'll consider changing to a div-based markup if necessary.

Comment: How about inserting the TR at the new position, after giving it a `height` of `0` and `overflow:hidden` … and then animate it’s height to the actual value? That would “push” the following TRs down slowly …

Comment: Ah -- that must be what the answers to this question were doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256581/animate-insertbefore-jquery. Thanks for explaining the technique. I tried it and it's still jerky because the subsequent table rows snap up before animating back down again. Maybe I can add an empty row in the old location of the moving row, then simultaneously animate its height to 0 while I animate the moved row's height back up to to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [jQuery sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)?

I think it will do what you are looking for.

Comment: That's the effect I have now: the table rows snap into their new positions with no animation. Now that I look again, is there no animation or just a very fast animation? If there is some animation then maybe slowing it down would give the desired effect.

Comment: I checked the documentation and I didn't see any references to the row movements being animated or the animation speed being adjustable: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/