# Move list elements to the top after being checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list with a series of li elements. Currently my code animates my li elements as they are clicked and change positions inside the ul.

I am trying to add some extra functionality depending on whether a li element has its checkbox checked or unchecked.

The behavior I am trying to get is the following:

1) If you check a box, it rises to the top of the list

2) if you uncheck it falls back behind the checked items, it does not matter whether it goes to to bottom or returns to its old position

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohithdm/k7rks2vt/)

This is a basic skeleton of what the HTML looks like:

```
<ul>
   <li class="js-checkbox" id="1"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number 1.</li>
   <li class="js-checkbox" id="2"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number 2.</li>
   <li class="js-checkbox" id="3"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number 3.</li>
   <li class="js-checkbox" id="4"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number 4.</li>
   <li class="js-checkbox" id="5"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number 5.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('ul > li > input[type="checkbox"]').on("click", function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent("li");
    if($(this).is(":checked") === true) {
    // move to the top
    $(parent).slideUp(300, function() {
      $(parent).prependTo($(parent).parent());
      $(parent).slideDown(300);
    });
    } else {
      $(parent).slideUp(300, function() {
        $(parent).appendTo($(parent).parent());
        $(parent).slideDown(300);
      });
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

li, ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li class="js-checkbox" id="1"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number 1.</li>
   <li class="js-checkbox" id="2"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number 2.</li>
   <li class="js-checkbox" id="3"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number 3.</li>
   <li class="js-checkbox" id="4"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number 4.</li>
   <li class="js-checkbox" id="5"><input type="checkbox">I am list item number 5.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So is my original animation not possible, where you see it as it flies up?

Comment: Same concept in my and his code can be used with .animate() function instead of slide up and down in the code. Just animate using top as you did before. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this:

```js
$("ul li input").on("change", function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var $li = self.parent();
  debugger;
  if (self.is(":checked")) {
    $li.slideUp(function() {
      $li.insertBefore($li.siblings(':eq(0)')).slideDown();
    });
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

li,
ul {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="js-checkbox" id="1">
    <input type="checkbox">I am list item number 1.</li>
  <li class="js-checkbox" id="2">
    <input type="checkbox">I am list item number 2.</li>
  <li class="js-checkbox" id="3">
    <input type="checkbox">I am list item number 3.</li>
  <li class="js-checkbox" id="4">
    <input type="checkbox">I am list item number 4.</li>
  <li class="js-checkbox" id="5">
    <input type="checkbox">I am list item number 5.</li>
</ul>
```

Credit for the animation goes to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256799/641530

Comment: This answer does not meet all the requirements mentioned by the author; namely the list items do not fall back.

Comment: It pretty much shows how to do it. I don't see how is it worth down-voting though, given it is pretty much the same code used for your answer.